# Is there anyway to reliably calculate the height of a UITextView?

Tags: ios, height, uitextview

I've tried `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode` and `sizeToFit`, both of which don't return the correct result.

The property `contentSize` is supposed to return the correct height, but it doesn't work until the text view is rendered to the screen, and I need to calculate the height before the text view is visible (it determines the height of a `UITableViewCell`.

Has anyone found any other method, a custom text view or the like, that correctly calculates the height of a UITextView?

**EDIT**
I should clarify that I want the ideal height based upon the text view's content.

Comment: UITextView.frame.size.height?

Comment: That does give us the height of a UITextView, but I'm looking ideal height based on its' content. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1):

IOS 7 does not supports the property `contentSize` anymore. Try using this

```
CGFloat textViewContentHeight = textView.contentSize.height;
textViewContentHeight = ceilf([textView sizeThatFits:textView.frame.size].height + 9);
```

this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
+ (CGFloat)heightOfComment:(NSString *)comment {
    UILabel *label = PrototypeCell.commentLabel;

    // NOTE: The height of the comment should always be at least the height of
    //       one line of text.
    if (comment.length == 0)
        comment = @" ";

    return [comment sizeWithFont:label.font
               constrainedToSize:label.frame.size
                   lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode].height;    
}
```

The key to making it work was `if (comment.length == 0) comment = @" ";`.

Comment: This works well for labels, and I've used it for label's before, but it isn't reliable for UITextViews.

Comment: Sorry, I've not tried it for UITextViews. What problem does it cause?

Answer (score 0):

When the techniques involving sizeToFit: and layouSubview don't work, I use this:

```
- (CGFloat)measureHeightOfUITextView:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if ([textView respondsToSelector:@selector(snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:)])
    {
        // This is the code for iOS 7. contentSize no longer returns the correct value, so
        // we have to calculate it.
        //
        // This is partly borrowed from HPGrowingTextView, but I've replaced the
        // magic fudge factors with the calculated values (having worked out where
        // they came from)

        CGRect frame = textView.bounds;

        // Take account of the padding added around the text.

        UIEdgeInsets textContainerInsets = textView.textContainerInset;
        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = textView.contentInset;

        CGFloat leftRightPadding = textContainerInsets.left + textContainerInsets.right + textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding * 2 + contentInsets.left + contentInsets.right;
        CGFloat topBottomPadding = textContainerInsets.top + textContainerInsets.bottom + contentInsets.top + contentInsets.bottom;

        frame.size.width -= leftRightPadding;
        frame.size.height -= topBottomPadding;

        NSString *textToMeasure = textView.text;
        if ([textToMeasure hasSuffix:@"\n"])
        {
            textToMeasure = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-", textView.text];
        }

        // NSString class method: boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context is
        // available only on ios7.0 sdk.

        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
        [paragraphStyle setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName: textView.font, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle };

        CGRect size = [textToMeasure boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(frame), MAXFLOAT)
                                                  options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                               attributes:attributes
                                                  context:nil];

        CGFloat measuredHeight = ceilf(CGRectGetHeight(size) + topBottomPadding);
        return measuredHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        return textView.contentSize.height;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Height is not available until the UITextview gets laid out. On iOS 6, addSubview (to a UIScrollView, for example) gave it layout values (i.e. frame.size.height). On iOS 7,this doesn't always happen - and for sizeToFit, the same is true.

I found some solutions, I prefer the one that does sizeToFit, then layoutIfNeeded before reading the (now changed) height:

```
...
[scrollView1 addSubview: myTextView];

    [myTextView sizeToFit]; //added
    [myTextView layoutIfNeeded]; //added

CGRect frame = myTextView.frame;
...
```

This is from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049532/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content-on-ios-7), see the notes. My attempt at explanation here is in the case this shouldn't be valid for UITextviews that are added to UITableViewCells instead of UIScrollViews (for some reason).

Comment: it doesn't make sense.