# UITextView setContentSize does not work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, contentsize

I want to change my UITextView's content size, and I tried as below:

```
[self.textView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.textView.contentSize.width, self.textView.contentSize.height+30)];
```

I found it doesn't work. What's more, I make it in a button's click event to see what will happen.

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender {
    static int y = 0;
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, 30, 30)];
    label.text = @"hello";
    y = y+30;
    [self.textView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.textView.contentSize.width, self.textView.contentSize.height+30)];
    NSLog(@"%f",self.textView.contentSize.height);
    [self.textView addSubview:label];
}
```

The result is the `setContentSize` doesn't work? What's more, contentSize just change for text content changing.

I want to know why, and Is there any method to change the UITextView's contentSize manually?

ADDITION: output for click action

```
2014-11-17 17:05:56.306 viewControllerAdvance[2371:607] 82.000000 
2014-11-17 17:05:56.455 viewControllerAdvance[2371:607] 82.000000
2014-11-17 17:05:56.638 viewControllerAdvance[2371:607] 82.000000
2014-11-17 17:05:56.772 viewControllerAdvance[2371:607] 82.000000
2014-11-17 17:05:56.923 viewControllerAdvance[2371:607] 82.000000
2014-11-17 17:05:57.072 viewControllerAdvance[2371:607] 82.000000
```

Comment: Can you please post your NSLog(@"%f",self.textView.contentSize.height); values after calling - (IBAction)click:(id)sender method few times?

Comment: Are you sure you need to set contentsize or frame

Comment: When you write the text in the textview the contentsize automatically increases and why you need to set it manually ??

Comment: @RameshMuthe, Actually, I want change some content word into tags (maybe using UILabel), just like StackOverFlow's adding tags. So maybe the textview's height is not content word's height.

Comment: Just do a cross check once whether you are resetting content size or allocating textview again

Comment: @thavasidurai, May you describe more details about it? I'm a freshbird.:p

Comment: are you allocating or resetting(content size) textview anywhere after click acton?

Comment: try by changing this line instead of yours  `[self.textView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.textView.contentSize.width, self.textView.contentSize.height+y)];`

Comment: tell me your exact requirement and I think in this way you can not handle the textview.If possible add the image what you need and think of different solution

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: @RameshMuthe, I just want to make an input box, which can make word into tags. It's something just like Stack over flow's adding tags step when you want to ask a question. It can make some of your word to become a tag, and you can continue to input after your tags. I want to make tags `inline` style in my text box

Comment: @KiranThapa, I dont know, how to check it?

Comment: @Shan, I think it's not the answer.

Comment: i know but your content view is increasing its height

Comment: Click the storyboard or xib file. On the file inspector pane (View -> Utilities -> Show File Inspector), there is "Interface Builder Document" section. There you will find the checkbox for whether you are using auto layout or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your method like below and check whether it meets your requirement or not.To use below way you need to add your text view on a scroll view and whenever you increase text view's height you suppose to increase scroll view's content size

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender { 

     static int y = 0;
     UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, y, 30, 30)];
     label.text = @"hello";
     y = y+30;
     [self.textView addSubview:label];

     CGFloat fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width;
     CGFloat dynamicHeight = textView.frame.size.height+30;

     CGSize newSize = [textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, dynamicHeight)];
     CGRect newFrame = textView.frame;
     newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, fmaxf(newSize.height, dynamicHeight));
     textView.frame = newFrame;

 }
```

Also set **textview.scrollEnabled = NO;**

Comment: Yeah, it's really meet my requirement! Thanks a lot!! But why `setContentSize` doesnt work?

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837178/resize-uitextview-according-to-its-content-in-ios7 it seems setting content size may not work in iOS 7