# How to make UITextView so high that it exactly fits the text content on iOS7?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a `UITextView` that's embedded into a `UIScrollView`. I would like the text view to not scroll and be exactly as high as required to show all of the text.
So the width is fixed and I set the content insets to indent the text a bit.

How do I get the correct height? I tried to set the frame's height to the content height but still it scrolls.

Comment: Calculate the required size of the display string. `boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`

Comment: check this answer: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content

Comment: James that method no longer works in iOS7, please see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19090599/1219698

Comment: More specifically this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18837714/556479

Comment: The referenced answer does not work on iOS7.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
-(void)resizeTextView
{
    CGRect  frame = _textView.frame;
    frame.size.height = [_textView sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, INFINITY)].height;
    _textView.frame = frame;
}
```