# How can I get a UILable height dynamically with HTML Content?

Tags: html, ios, uitextview

I am having one query. I googled it alot but not able to find out its solution.

I am using one api in which I am getting content as HTML string.

Now I want to set that data to UITextView. 
Now to calculate the height of the UITextView firstly I was using

```
CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(width-MARGIN - (6 * 2), 20000.0f);
    // Get the size of the text given the CGSize we just made as a constraint
    CGSize size = [lbltitle.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:custom_font_name size:lbltitle.font.pointSize] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    int lines = size.height / lbltitle.font.pointSize + 1;

    [lbltitle setFrame: CGRectMake(lbltitle.frame.origin.x,lbltitle.frame.origin.y,width-MARGIN, lbltitle.font.pointSize * lines)];
```

but now when I am passing the html content it's generating the height more then the needed. So what is the solution to calculate the height of the UITextview with HTML text.
I am using below code to assign HTML text to UITextView.

```
[txtdescription setValue:data.desc forKey:@"contentToHTMLString"];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I size a UITextView to its content on iOS 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049532/how-do-i-size-a-uitextview-to-its-content-on-ios-7)

Comment: I want it to work ios 5 above

Comment: The question I linked to has an answer that should have everything you need to fix the problem, including on iOS 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I found solution of my own question

https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser

I need to convert first HTML text to plain text then I can calculate the size.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `UIWebView` intead of `UITextView`

Here

```
NSData* htmlData = [ content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                [webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

Comment: but if I use UIWebView then how can I get the size of UIWebview? and its a iterative list in UITableView so if I will use UIWebView then it will take more load and more memory

Comment: you draw your web view expanding all the screen with background color is clear. Now html string will have with it and it will draw for . you dont need to calculate size.

Comment: but its in UITableView with customcell then how to size the table row height?

Comment: why not you try attributed string .  http://initwithfunk.com/blog/2013/09/29/easy-markdown-rendering-with-nsattributedstring-on-ios-7/